# Why does console in R Studio only allow partial commands?

Tags: console

I am trying to advance my R knowledge, but RStudio gets very frustrating: I paste in my work / or re-enact a how-to, but console complains too much; also Ctrl-Enter only works in the text-editor.

After hours of debugging, I had to put a command in piece by piece, and then a random internet search said I should not code in console. I am not coding, I am taking a class and pasting examples; but coding is possible in Console. Now, I have to rethink my whole strategy and take notes in R. Kind of makes me think of applescript or javascript programming where you see the code and only debug in console; but should have been labeled that way...I have been tinkering off and on for a year now. I wish I had a keyboard shortcut/format to paste in console just to test a code: Like \ or +, etc.

Note: I had to define a few variables and enable

```
    Library(dslabs)
    Library(dplyr) gives group_by, %>%
    Library(purrr) gives map_dbl
```

```
accuracy <- map_dbl(cutoff, function(x){
  y_hat <- ifelse(train_set$height > x, "Male", "Female") %>% 
    factor(levels = levels(test_set$identifier))
mean(y_hat == train_set$identifier)})
```

Console says: "Error: unexpected symbol in "accuracy <- map_dbl(cutoff, function(x){ y_hat <- ifelse(train_set$height > x, "Male", "Female") %>% factor(levels = levels(test_set$identifier)) mean"

Turns out > "console" has to run the first part before a logical space/break or {; then give "+" and take the final arguments and } or )

The editor just works right.

Partial answer at https://www.dummies.com:

"To prepare your script to be sourced, you first write the entire script in an editor window. In RStudio, for example, the editor window is in the top-left corner of the screen. Whenever you press Enter in the editor window, the cursor moves to the next line, as in any text editor" (de Vries, and Meys, J. (n.d.) Programming: R: How to Source a Script in R. Dummies: A Wiley Brand. https://www.dummies.com/programming/r/how-to-source-a-script-in-r ).

Why doesn't console tell you to try the editor window, allow customization, or just work without breaking it into steps, such as a nifty library() for console?

Answer (score 0):

RStudio is very deliberate. It wants you to write chunks of source code in the top-left window called "Editor." Besides tidyverse or dplyr providing redirect abilities, errors happen because %>% is used to direct output between more than one line of code; and multiple lines cannot be done from console easily.

Yes, console accepts code, but it won't recognize more than a single function. Meaning if it sees ) } or %>% that is the end of the function. And you need a new line. Enter the code up to the %>% and hit enter.

Example:

```
height %>% #enter
```

Console will add the + itself.

Keep coding.
After the last ) such as in factor(); console will return to a new line, and "mean," will run by itself.

Remember: %>% points to the next line of code. So RStudio's console needs you to paste in the code piece-by-piece and physically press "enter" or "return" after each %>%

Instructors might not give the code to you in context, which can be frustrating, because a section of code will depend on functions defined earlier to work. Look for instructor notes about different versions of R; or the instructors samples and handouts to get the full context; if not ask the instructor; my instructors code was correct, just not without the tidbits before which were not provided. Once I got those the results were the same and/or more accurate.

In summary:

To make coding easier, build examples in the Editor, like this:

Start a new RMarkdown document using File > New File > R Markdown... and name it.

This opens a new document with author info and simple howto examples as runnable chunks of code

Start taking notes, then start a new line, and type three ``` (called back-tick on the ~ key).

Let editor offset it by typing ```{r, include=TRUE}

````
```{r, include=TRUE}
cutoff <- seq(61, 70)
accuracy <- map_dbl(cutoff, function(x){
y_hat <- ifelse(train_set$height > x, "Male", "Female") %>% 
 factor(levels = levels(test_set$identifier))
mean(y_hat == train_set$identifier)})
```
````

Now you have a workable chunk of source code. You can Run it in console by clicking the green play button "Run Current Chunk," include=TRUE tells it to draw the tables beneath the code so you can see them yourself.